# Running RabbitMQ With JWT Authentication Behind Corporate Proxy

Tags: rabbitmq, http-proxy

We have a stack consist of:

- RabbitMQ (RMQ) with `rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2` plugin enabled that fetches the keys from our Keycloak:

```
  {rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2, [
    {resource_server_id, <<"rabbitmq">>},
    {key_config, [
      {jwks_url, "${OIDC_BASE_URL}/protocol/openid-connect/certs"}
    ]}
  ]}
```

- Data publisher that publishes data via AMQP to RMQ
- Nginx that exposes an endpoint for STOMP
- Clients that consume data via STOMP (accessing the RMQ with their JWT tokens)

Everything works in our stack in normal conditions but when we run the stack behind a corporate proxy we face the issue.

RMQ receives the connections from STOMP clients but it cannot verify the tokens since it cannot get the key from our Keycloak (because of proxy it cannot reach out).

We solved this issue for other components of our stack by setting environment variables such as `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy`.

I passed these variables to the RMQ as below but still, it cannot parse the JWT token:

```yaml
  broker:
    image: docker.io/broker:latest
    environment:
      OIDC_BASE_URL: "https://my-keycloak.io/auth/realms/my-realm"
      http_proxy: "http://1.1.1.1:8080"
      https_proxy: "http://1.1.1.1:8080"
      no_proxy: "nginx,project_mgr,localhost,127.0.0.1"
      HTTP_PROXY: "http://1.1.1.1:8080"
      HTTPS_PROXY: "http://1.1.1.1:8080"
      NO_PROXY: "nginx,project_mgr,localhost,127.0.0.1"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
      - "15674:15674"
    networks:
      - local-network
```

RMQ logs:

```
2024-01-31 14:21:17.102107+00:00 [warn] <0.2042.0> Description: "Authenticity is not established by certificate path validation"
2024-01-31 14:21:17.102107+00:00 [warn] <0.2042.0>      Reason: "Option {verify, verify_peer} and cacertfile/cacerts is missing"
2024-01-31 14:21:17.102107+00:00 [warn] <0.2042.0> 
2024-01-31 14:21:25.103685+00:00 [warn] <0.2036.0> STOMP login failed for user '': authentication failed
2024-01-31 14:21:25.103845+00:00 [erro] <0.2036.0> STOMP error frame sent:
2024-01-31 14:21:25.103845+00:00 [erro] <0.2036.0> Message: "Bad CONNECT"
2024-01-31 14:21:25.103845+00:00 [erro] <0.2036.0> Detail: "Access refused for user ''\n"
2024-01-31 14:21:25.103845+00:00 [erro] <0.2036.0> Server private detail: none
```

So what is the solution in this case? I couldn't find that much info on how to run RMQ behind corporate proxy set aside fetching key and working with JWT.